# Implicitly defined random variable

Tags: distributions, random-variable

Recently I came across the following problem: Let $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ be a function as smooth as we want (even analytic if this is convinient) such that the equation $f(x,y)=0$ for every $x$ has a unique root and let $x$ be a random variable with known CDF (or even PDF if it is more convinient). Let $y$ be the random variable defined by $f(x,y)=0$, what can we say about its distribution? Can we get at least the first few moments in a straightforward way?

I understand that if we can write $y=g(x)$ for some "nice" $g$ we can use the results for the transformation of random variables, but what if we cannot really write $g$? Is there any theory that covers that?

Moreover, if we drop the assumption that for every $x$ the equation $f(x,y)=0$ has a unique root, what can we say?

For example let's say that $f(x,y)=x+y(y-1)(y-2)$. In this case if $x\in[-\frac{2}{3\sqrt{3}},\frac{2}{3\sqrt{3}}]$ the equation $f(x,y)=0$ has multiple roots. So let us define $y$ to be the root with the smallest absolute value, this is a well defined random variable. What can we say about its distribution? Is there any textbook covering such cases?

Comment: Welcome to our site. Please note that you will run into the usual multiplicity problems for transformations of random variables unless the function implicitly defined by the zeros of $f$ is also one-to-one, which would lead one to expect that little could be said in general.  BTW, presumably "$F$" means the same as $f.$

Comment: @whuber thanks for picking this up. I corrected it. My background is analysis and not statistics, so I am unaware of the multiplicity problem. Is there any introductory book you would suggest to read about these things?